# Recursive script Delete folders by name all but 2

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to write a recursive script to delete all folders in a subfolder named 'date-2012-01-01_12_30' but leave the two latest.

/var/www/temp/updates/ then hundreds of folders by 'date' and by 'code'

e.g.

```
/var/www/temp/updates/2012-01-01/temp1/date-2012-01-_12_30
/var/www/temp/updates/2012-01-01/temp1/date-2012-02-_13_30
/var/www/temp/updates/2012-01-01/temp1/date-2013-11-_12_30
/var/www/temp/updates/2012-01-01/temp2/date-2012-01-_12_30
```

I was thinking about using a find to get the folder but unsure how to know what folders I can delete as the script will have to know how date- folders are in that subfolder and which  ones are the latest ones

Hmm, any help would be great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
find /var/www/temp/updates/ -type d -name "date-*" -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | head -n -2 | cut -f2- | xargs rm -rf
```

`find` prints out the directory paths along with their last modification times. This is then sorted and all but the last two are deleted.

Comment: Hi all the date folder will be differently named so you will have at least five different folders in one subfolder named date-(time the folder was made)

Comment: My command should still work. The `find` command will look recursively under all directories in `/var/www/temp/updates/`.

Comment: I've changed it to echo to test and nothing is shown... am I doing something wrong

Comment: I've changed the find to this to get it working -type d -name date-* -printf '%T@ %p\n' -exec echo '{}' \; | sort -n | head -n -2

Comment: @Grimlockz You must add the echo to `xargs` for testing: `find /var/www/temp/updates/ -type d -name "date-*" -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | head -n -2 | xargs echo rm -rf`

Comment: @Grimlockz Although, you must `cut` the timestamp before `rm`: `find /var/www/temp/updates/ -type d -name "date-*" -printf '%T@\t%p\n' | sort -n | cut -f2- | head -n -2 | xargs echo rm`

Answer (score 1):

If all folders are in subdirectories `temp1`, `temp2`, ..., you can just use `ls -tr`

```
ls -dtr /var/www/temp/updates/2012-01-01/temp*/* | head -n -2 | xargs rm -rf
```

This lists all folders sorted by time `ls -dtr`, takes all but the two latest `head` and removes the remaining folders `xargs rm -rf`.

Comment: Actually the folders with all be different dates and named with unique codes... probably about 100,000 thousand folders

Comment: @Grimlockz That's too much for the command line then. You must use find and sort as dogbane suggested. What unique codes do you mean?